# подскажите пожалуйста как сделать remove у активного класса при нажатии на другой, чтобы не открывалось большой одной панели в аккордеоне?

Tags: javascript, accordion

```
<div class="estate out">
                        <div class="estate_text">
                            <p class="main_subtitle out">Часто задаваемые</p>
                            <p class="main_title out">ВОПРОСЫ И ОТВЕТЫ</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estate_out_content">
                            <div class="question">
                                <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
                                <span>Почему северный Кипр привлектальное место для инвестиций?</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="answer">
                                <div class="answer_content">
                                    <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
                                <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
                                <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
                                <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estate_out_content">
                            <div class="question">
                                <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
                                <span>Как оплатить недвижимость?</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="answer">
                                <div class="answer_content">
                                    <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
                                <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
                                <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
                                <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estate_out_content">
                            <div class="question">
                                <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
                                <span>Как прилететь и нужна ли виза на Северный Кипр?</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="answer">
                                <div class="answer_content">
                                    <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
                                <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
                                <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
                                <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estate_out_content">
                            <div class="question">
                                <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
                                <span>Как оформить недвижимость?</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="answer">
                                <div class="answer_content">
                                    <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
                                <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
                                <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
                                <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estate_out_content">
                            <div class="question">
                                <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
                                <span>Как купить недвижимость в рассрочку?</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="answer">
                                <div class="answer_content">
                                    <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
                                <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
                                <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
                                <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="estate_out_content">
                            <div class="question">
                                <img src="./images/images/arrow_right.png" alt="" width="15px" height="7px" class="arrow">
                                <span>Почему безопасно покупать на Северном Кипре?</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="answer">
                                <div class="answer_content">
                                    <span class="answer_title">Северный Кипр, официально известный как Турецкая Республика Северного Кипра, имеет ряд привлекательных особенностей, которые делают его интересным местом для инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>1.Экономический потенциал: Северный Кипр обладает значительным потенциалом для экономического развития. Он предлагает привлекательные возможности для инвестиций в различные секторы, такие как туризм, недвижимость, образование и здравоохранение. Экономика региона стремится к диверсификации и привлечению иностранных инвестиций.</span>
                                <span>2.Налоговые льготы: Северный Кипр предлагает привлекательные налоговые льготы для предпринимателей и инвесторов. Здесь действует низкая ставка налога на прибыль, иностранные инвесторы освобождаются от налога на наследство и дивиденды, а также предоставляются льготы на налог на недвижимость.</span>
                                <span>3.Развитая инфраструктура: Северный Кипр имеет хорошо развитую инфраструктуру, включая сети дорог, аэропорты, порты и телекоммуникационные системы. Это облегчает бизнес-деятельность и делает регион более доступным для международных инвесторов.</span>
                                <span>4.Природные ресурсы и туризм: Северный Кипр располагает прекрасными природными ресурсами, включая красивые пляжи, горы и исторические достопримечательности. Туризм является одним из ключевых секторов экономики региона, и здесь есть возможности для инвестиций в отели, курорты, рестораны и развлекательные объекты.</span>
                                <span>5.Поддержка правительства: Правительство Северного Кипра предпринимает шаги для привлечения иностранных инвестиций и создания благоприятной деловой среды. Были введены реформы в систему лицензирования и регулирования бизнеса, а также предоставлены различные стимулы и льготы для инвесторов.
                                </span>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- <figure class="bg-img-base" style="background-image:url(./images/images/.png); width: 100%; height: 500px; background-size: 100% 100%;"></figure> -->
                        

                    </div>
    


let acc = document.querySelectorAll('.estate_out_content');

acc.forEach(function(item) {
  let answer = item.querySelector('.answer');
  let arrow = item.querySelector('.arrow');
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(item.classList.contains('active')){
        item.classList.remove('active') 
        console.log(item);
    }
    else{
        item.classList.toggle('active');
        console.log(item);
    }
    item.classList.toggle('active');
    item.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let acc = document.querySelectorAll('.estate_out_content');

acc.forEach(function(item) {
  let answer = item.querySelector('.answer');
  let arrow = item.querySelector('.arrow');

  item.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let allActive = document.querySelectorAll('.active'); //Если происходит клик, то находим все элементы с классом active

    for (let i = 0; i < allActive.length; i++) { //Удаляем у всех найденных элементов класс active
      allActive[i].classList.remove('active');
    }

    if (!item.contains(allActive[0])) { //Выполняется, если у элемента нет дочерних элементов с классом active

      answer.classList.add('active');
      arrow.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
});
```